# WAMP tray icon is unresponsive despite being green

Tags: windows, localhost, wamp

I installed WAMP version 3.3.2 yesterday and the tray icon is completely unresponsive to both left and right clicks, so I can’t change any settings or shut it down. I’ve only found a couple threads on the internet, both 7+ years old, that had this same issue, but neither were of much help.

I am otherwise not having any issue with WAMP. I've reinstalled several times, verified that I have all the necessary VC packages, I don't have skype, and IIS is disabled. The only thing I can't do is left or right click the tray icon.

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: Did you tried to kill all relevant processes? (i.e. AeTrayMenu & Apache)